# Find an Equation of the Tangent Plane to the Given Parametric Surface at the Specified Point.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

I am given $x=u+v$, $y=3u^2$, and $z=u-v$. I need to find the equation of the tangent plane at $(2,3,0)$. I understand that the equation of the tangent plane is $z=f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$, since $z_0=0$. I have determined that $u=1$ and $v=1$ at $(2,3,0)$.

I'm confused as to how I determine $f_x$ and $f_y$ since my coordinates are in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your formula is for the tangent plane to a graph of the form $z = f(x, y)$, but your surface is expressed parametrically as
$$
S: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R^3: (u, v) \mapsto (u+v, 3u^2, u-v)
$$

For that, the equation looks more like

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x - x_0 \\
x - y_0 \\
z - z_0
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot \mathbf w = 0
$$
where 
$$
\mathbf w = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (u_0, v_0) \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (u_0, v_0).
$$

The two partials are tangent to your surface, so their cross product is normal to the tangent plane.